# flexmix not displaying parameters with multinomial model FLXMRmultinom

Tags: multinomial, mixture-model

I have used stepFlexmix in R to find a number of clusters. Here is what I did:

`formula <- as.formula(y ~ x + x^2)`

`flex <- flexmix::stepFlexmix(. ~ . | id, data=df, k=1:5,`
`nrep=50, control = list(iter.max = 500, minprior = 0),`
`model = flexmix::FLXMRmultinom(formula, varFix=T, fixed = ~ 0))`

When I pull out the solution with the lowest BIC:

`chosen_flex <- getModel(flex, "BIC")`

And ask for the parameters of the model:

`parameters(chosen_flex, component = 1)`

I am not able to see the parameter labels:

`Comp.1`
`coef1 -0.36435045`
`coef2 -5.55371253`
`coef3 -2.69839653`
`coef4 0.02251283`
`coef5 0.66133089`
`coef6 0.66509508`

You are supposed to be able to see something like:

`Comp.1`
`coef.(Intercept) -0.20866478`
`coef.x 4.81612095`
`coef.I(x^2) 0.03632578`
`sigma 3.47494722`

*taken from page 5 https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/flexmix/vignettes/flexmix-intro.pdf

Does anyone know what's going on here? How can I extract the parameter labels?

I tried to run parameters() and get labels for coefficients but I don't see the labels.